# How can I upgrade the SSD cache drive in my HP Envy 700-215xt?

Tags: ssd, hard-drive-cache

I have the 16g drive right now, and at some point I'd like to upgrade that to a 32g or 64g drive. Is this as easy as swapping out the drive or does the cache drive have files on it my computer has to have to work?

Comment: Have you check the service manual for this device?  I am going to guess its not easy and likely not possible due the type of part that is used ( its likely a soldered solution ).

Comment: Remove the 16GB mSATA SSD drive, and replace it with a larger-capacity mSATA SSD drive (that Intel RST controller should handle up to a 64GB cache). Where are you getting stuck exactly?

Comment: I'm not getting stuck, I just didn't see anything about it anywhere.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Is that a typical setup? How do I know if my computer uses Intel RST?

Comment: I read the specs on [HP's site](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=ca&lc=en&docname=c04094823). It says you have an [Intel H87 chipset](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/mainstream-chipsets/h87-chipset.html) which supports [RST](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/rapid-storage-technology) which includes [Smart Response Technology](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/smart-response-technology.html) for the SSD caching.

Comment: To whomever downvoted me, I did not know that the Intel H87 chipset  supported RST nor did I even know to look there.